# Access to font not allowed by CORS Policy

Tags: themes

I'm getting the following problem on a site I'm developing:

Access to Font at 'hxttps://tanit.com.co/wp-content/themes/betheme/fonts/mfn-icons.woff?23391439' from origin 'hxttps://www.tanit.com.co' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'https://www.tanit.com.co' is therefore not allowed access.

What do you think it might be?

Comment: how is your host/site settings the control allow origin header? It has 2 values no 1 it should be `*` not `*,*`

Comment: What is 'hxttps'?

Answer (score 1):

First check your blog **Settings > General settings**. You need to decide what you primary site url will be, *www.tinit.com.co* or *tinit.com.co*. Make sure your **WordPress Address** and **Site Address** are set accordingly to the correct values. The fact you encounter this problem means your web server setup allows requests to both www.tinit.com.co and tinit.com.co to point to one file path (where you WP install resides). You should decide on what URL will be primary for your blog and redirect the other one to it. Redirection is best done on the web server. Try searching it out.